# Behavior of multiple HighCharts on single page when removing one div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, highcharts

Please refer to http://jsfiddle.net/epoch/bCU2E/1/ .

```
<div id="graph" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
<div id="sales" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
<div id="addsales" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Three HighChart graphs are displayed; one corresponding to each div line above. If you go into the HTML window and remove the div line for id="graph" and re-run, only one chart will be displayed.

Why is it that removing one div removes two charts?

Now please copy and paste this same id="graph" div line so that there are two "graph" div lines followed by the "sales" and the "addsales" div lines.

```
<div id="graph" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
<div id="graph" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
<div id="sales" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
<div id="addsales" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Please re-run.

Why is it that a blank graph area is inserted? Why will it not insert another copy of the "Traffic by source" chart? I am guessing that this has to do with the fact that the previous instance of the "graph" div directed the second copy to the first graph div area because the naming has already been established. If the names are all locked in, then why does it create the blank chart area in the first place?

If this is due to the div naming, then without touching the javascript window, is there any way to cause two instances of the "Traffic by source" chart to become visible? What if altering the javascript was allowed but creating another var chart was not? Is it possible to produce two instances of the "Traffic by source" chart?

I am asking these question because I see this as a necessary stepping stone in learning how to really manipulate multiple charts on a single page. I am trying to construct say 20 charts and leave it to a user to select which of the charts to display and also allow the user to control the layout order and position of the selected charts. Any suggestions would be most helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Although I'm not an expert in Highcharts, I'll try to give the answers to your questions.

> 1. Why is it that removing one div removes two charts?

This is because Highcharts throws exception ([Highcharts Error #13](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.renderTo)), it cannot find the specified div to render to (`graph`). But because the `graph` div is rendered the second (after `sales`), the `sales` div is rendered ok, and then exception occurs, so Highcharts stops rendering other elements. Simple check - try removing `sales` div - none of charts is rendered, because exception is thrown on the first div.

> 1. Why is it that a blank graph area is inserted? Why will it not insert another copy of the "Traffic by source" chart?

Well, this is my assumption, but I think Highcharts simply ignores copies of the div with the same `id` if it already have found one. You can't just copy and paste divs like that because:

1. It is strongly discouraged to use the same `id` for DOM elements.
2. Highcharts uses [renderTo](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.renderTo) property to search by Id and uses only first found element.
   The "blank copy" is actually your copied div, it has width and height, so it is displayed on page as an empty block.

Answer (score 0):

For the first problem you're creating the first graph successfully but the second one hits a javascript error looking for the missing div then stops the code execution (That's just how JS works).

For the second problem you're seeing an empty spot because IDs in HTML are supposed to be unique. The chart library is only looking for a single location. To create a duplicate of a chart repeat the chart code with a different ID passed to chart's rendorTo value shown here:

```
var chart;
$(document).ready(function () {
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'ThisMustBeUnique',
            type: 'area'
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Why is it that removing one div removes two charts?**

Because your Javascript throws an error when it realizes that container isn't there, and stops executing code. The code for the last chart is never executed (graph is number 2 of 3 in your Javascript).

> **Why is it that a blank graph area is inserted?**

Highcharts will choose the first one as the container. I'm guessing because jQuery/Javascript will just take the first one when searching by ID. You can see that jQuery definately only returns the first one when doing this code:

```
console.log($('#graph'));
```

This is as intended.

> **Why does it create the blank chart area in the first place?**

Your CSS defines the size of the `div`, not Highcharts. Your CSS for the div:

```
min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto
```

This is causing the blank space.

> **Without touching the javascript window, is there any way to cause two instances of the "Traffic by source" chart to become visible? ... What if altering the javascript was allowed but creating another var chart was not? Is it possible to produce two instances of the "Traffic by source" chart?**

Do it in Javascript. To display two charts based on the same options just save the options in a variable and create them separately, like so:

```
var options = {
    chart: {
        type: 'area'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Sales by source'
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false,
    },
    //...more options
}

$('#container1').highcharts(options);
$('#container2').highcharts(options);
```

Comment: Might you have a suggestion for handling the 20 charts available, user selects which charts to display and their placement question that I referred to in the lower part of my post?

Comment: It's a bit of a broad description. Create 20 charts. Listen for some click on charts for selection and drag for ordering. Many frameworks for placement , like [Gridster](http://gridster.net/), [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/)... You'll have to make a choice on which one yourself.